# How to add pagination's get parameter to the end of the url?

Tags: php, pagination

I'm using pagination and also advantage search options in a page.

Search is working great. For example, when I use the search, url is like this:

```
http://example.com/category/contents?**title=test&year=2015&author=test**
```

It's okay. But when I use the pagination links, all search parameters are gone..

```
http://example.com/category/contents?**page=3**
```

How can I solve this?

I want to do this:

```
http://example.com/category/contents?title=test&year=2015&author=test&**page=3**
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, I'm using like that now:

```
$parameters = "";

if(isset($_GET["x_param"])){
    $parameters .= "&parametername=".$_GET["x_param"]    
}
```

And I'm adding the $parameters variable to the end of pagination links.

```
?page=xx".$parameters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the required values from URL in variables like follow.

```
$title="";

if(isset($_GET["name"])) {
   $title=$_GET["title"];
}
```

In above code we're saving value of title parameter in $title variable if it is set. You can do the same for other values.

Now pass this values when you're hitting the next or previous page along with page number.

Comment: I did it. Is it bad way or okay?

Comment: No it isn't bad way to use URL parameters like that.

Answer (score -1):

In pagination you need to change parameter from http:://mysite.com/category/contents?page=3

to

http:://mysite.com/category/contents?page=3&title=$_REQUEST['title']&year=$_REQUEST['year']&author=$_REQUEST['author']

Comment: foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value){
    $requestparameters.=$key.'='.$value;
    }
echo $requestparameters; 
$requestparameters should show you all parameters send through search .